# Problem: Connection between cross ratio and collinearity

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, cross-ratio

In $ \mathbb{RP}^2$ given a triangle $A_1A_2A_3$  and a point $P$ not lying on either one of the edges , set points $$B_i = PA_i \cap A_kA_l,\  k,l \not= i \ \forall i$$ next choose points $C_i \in PA_i\  \forall i$ and calculate the cross ratio $(A_i, B_i,P,C_i)=a_i\  \forall i$.

Show that $C_1, C_3, C_3$ are collinear if and only if $a_1+a_2+a_3=2+a_1a_2a_3$.

I appreciate any help, especially hints as i have no good idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Start by drawing some pictures of the configuration.

Comment: @amd i did and it is definitly possible that the three points are collinear (there are infinitely many constellations that would work), but i have honestly no clue how to connect them to the cross ratio(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup is invariant under projective transformations, so without loss of generality choose $$A_1=[1:0:0]\qquad A_2=[0:1:0]\qquad A_3=[0:0:1]$$ Then with $P=[p_1:p_2:p_3]$ you get $$B_1=[0:p_2:p_3]\qquad B_2=[p_1:0:p_3]\qquad B_3=[p_1:p_2:0]$$ either via cross-product computation or by observing that points on $A_2A_3$ have a zero in the first place, and $B_1=P-p_1A_1$ is exactly the linear combination of $P$ and $A_1$ which satisfies this property. Likewise for other two. Similarly you can assume $C_i=\lambda_i P+\mu_i A_i$ and then compute the cross ratio with respect to the basis $P,A_i$ as

$$a_i=(A_i,B_i;P,C_i)=
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-p_i\end{bmatrix};
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_i\\\mu_i\end{bmatrix}
\right)=\\
\frac
{\begin{vmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{vmatrix}\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}1&\lambda_i\\-p_i&\mu_i\end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}0&\lambda_i\\1&\mu_i\end{vmatrix}\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\-p_i&0\end{vmatrix}}=
\frac{\mu_i+\lambda_ip_i}{\lambda_ip_i}\\
\lambda_ip_ia_i=\mu_i+\lambda_ip_i\\
0=\mu_i+\lambda_ip_i(1-a_i)$$
Solutions to this are as usual only defined up to some scalar factor, but one simple solution would be the following:
$$\mu_i=p_i(a_i-1)\qquad \lambda_i=1\\
C_i=P + p_i(a_i-1)A_i
$$

All three points are collinear if their determinant vanishes.

$$0=\det[C_1,C_2,C_3]=\begin{vmatrix}
p_1+p_1(a_1-1) & p_1 & p_1 \\
p_2 & p_2+p_2(a_2-1) & p_2 \\
p_3 & p_3 & p_3+p_3(a_3-1)
\end{vmatrix}$$

The rest is just a bit of algebra.

Comment: Hello. I am not a math major. But I would appreciate if someone can explain the diffrerence between the cross ratio of a collinear set of points and the noncollinear case . In layman terms if possible .

Comment: @user91411: cross ratio for non-collinear points is not generally defined. Depending on circumstances, sometimes a specific definition makes sense. Sometimes you want the cross ratio "as seen from a certain point". This is in fact the cross ratio of the lines connecting that designated point to the four points of the cross ratio. Sometimes it makes sense to use an ideal circle point with complex coordinates $[1:i:0]$ as the designated point, so cross ratios are complex numbers. Unless they lie on a line or circle. This corresponds to seeing the plane as a complex projective line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What do you exactly mean by cross-ratio is not defined for non-collinear points?  To me,  the algebraic cross ratio formula still makes sense for a set of points on the complex plane which do not necessarily lie on a line/circle, but in this case cross-ratio may be a complex number. However it still is an invariant under Mobius group.

Comment: @user91411: If you feed complex numbers into the cross ratio formula, you're operating in $\mathbb{CP}^1$, the complex projective line i.e. [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere). Seen as a single complex line, all points are "collinear". Seen as a compactified real plane, cross ratio can't distinguish between collinearity and cocircularity as Möbius transformations convert between these two but leave the cross ratio invariant. As I said, real cross ratio corresponds to collinear or cocircular points. The question here was about real plane so this is off topic.